# Pandas: dataframe to array of rows with index as additional column

Tags: pandas

With panda, when I print a dataframe, my result is

```
   Description Test
0        Some    3
1       Thing    e
2        Test  NaN
```

For my front end I need two things: one is an object array of headers, and the other is an object array of rows. The first is not a problem, I made that with `columns` and a function. The rows however are trickier. I need this result:

```
[
{'id': 0, 'description':'some', 'test':'3'},
{'id': 1, 'description':'Thing', 'test':'e'},
{'id': 2, 'description':'Test', 'test':'NaN'},
]
```

The `NaN` is an empty, I forgot to pass a value for it. I could make a funtion and use pydash with some loops maybe, but is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset current numeric index to a named column `id` and convert dataframe into list of records, with a single line:

```
df.reset_index(names='id').to_dict('records')
```

---

```
[{'id': 0, 'Description': 'Some', 'Test': '3'},
 {'id': 1, 'Description': 'Thing', 'Test': 'e'},
 {'id': 2, 'Description': 'Test', 'Test': nan}]
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted